# The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration' is not allowed for this page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

Search Service application worked fine before but after some days when i open search service application from central admin below error appears.

> The base type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration' is
> not allowed for this page. The type
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchAdministration,
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not
> registered as safe.

what cause this issue occurred in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed any patches recently?

Anyway，Either add the safecontrol to your config file or update the SearchResults.aspx page layout's top section.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVUPWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Comment: Hi I installed NOV SP 2013 Security patches recently , Please can you share above Html from where you posted any references for that